# Subset of stream's changelog and repartition partitions not available as broker is down - how stream should behave?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

My setup consists of 3 kafka brokers (2.11-1.1.1), a single ZK and a java service that is using the Streams API.

The java service is consuming from topic A, performs a persistent stream operation (backed up by a changelog and a repartition streams topic) and writes to topic B. EOS semantics are enabled.

Given that the changelog and repartition topics have replication factor of 1, how should the streams java app behave in case one of my brokers is down (e.g. in my DEV env the disk is full only for one broker). Will the stream continue to consume even if 1/3 of the changelog and repartition partitions are not reachable?

EDIT: Also given that topics A, B and __consumer_offsets have RF=3.

In my java service logs I see:

```
2019-01-04 09:14:38,787 UTC WARN kafka-producer-network-thread | trsb-app- 
nonprod.snapshot-14fa12b2-ac15-4ecc-8729-8f6c4a0034a7-StreamThread-2-0_4- 
producer org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient warn | [Producer 
clientId=trsb-app-nonprod.snapshot-14fa12b2-ac15-4ecc-8729-8f6c4a0034a7- 
StreamThread-2-0_4-producer, transactionalId=trsb-app-nonprod.snapshot-0_4] 
Connection to node 1 could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2019-01-04 09:14:38,797 UTC WARN kafka-producer-network-thread | trsb-app- 
nonprod.snapshot-14fa12b2-ac15-4ecc-8729-8f6c4a0034a7-StreamThread-2-1_10- 
producer org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient warn | [Producer 
clientId=trsb-app-nonprod.snapshot-14fa12b2-ac15-4ecc-8729-8f6c4a0034a7- 
StreamThread-2-1_10-producer, transactionalId=trsb-app-nonprod.snapshot- 
1_10] Connection to node 1 could not be established. Broker may not be 
available.
```

And nothing is consumed.

In both working broker logs I see:

```
[2019-01-04 13:56:56,449] WARN Resetting first dirty offset of trsb-app- 
nonprod.snapshot-store.invoices-changelog-43 to log start offset 99 since 
the checkpointed offset 95 is invalid. (kafka.log.LogCleanerManager$)
[2019-01-04 13:56:56,449] WARN Resetting first dirty offset of trsb-app- 
nonprod.snapshot-store.invoices-changelog-40 to log start offset 103 since 
the checkpointed offset 100 is invalid. (kafka.log.LogCleanerManager$)
```

Comment: for Kafka Stream you can set `replication.factor` property, be default it is 1

Comment: @wardziniak fair point, but I am looking to find out if the above behavior is the "expected" one. Is it expected the stream to stop consuming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stream continues to consume, but as the state store, depending on the message key, may no be pushable to its corresponding changelog partition, some keys may fail and these transactions will fail and be rollbacked. As a result, the first key on topic A that once consumed will cause the state store push to fail, will block its partition till the broker is up again. This is because the state store push is part of the EOS transaction.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using exactly once semantics, a minimum of 3 brokers are needed to continue processing, so your app would not continue to process if one of the brokers went down. Read here (see processing.guarantee section) for more info regarding this:

https://kafka.apache.org/10/documentation/streams/developer-guide/config-streams.html#id25

Comment: thanks, very good point! This could explain why my consumer is not consuming. But still, my question can be restated as "I have 5 brokers and one is down (4 >= 3), if changelog and repartition topics have RF=1 (eos does not automatically alter the RF), then 1/5 of their partitions will not be accessible by the streams internal producer. Will the stream consume?"

Comment: Hmm, I am not 100% sure on this. I would think that the application would continue to stream, but that is mainly a guess. This is all that the documentation states: 

`Increase the replication factor to 3 to ensure that the internal Kafka Streams topic can tolerate up to 2 broker failures. `.

Comment: yep.. but if is continues to stream doesn't this mean that the production to the stream internal topics (e.g. pushing the local store to them) are not part of the transaction? By transaction I refer to the consumption of a message from topic A and its production to topic B.

Comment: Definitely local state store updates are part of a transaction as explained here:  https://www.confluent.io/blog/enabling-exactly-kafka-streams/

Comment: My assumption is that either it stops consuming or it continues but as the state store, depending on the message key, may no be pushable to its corresponding changelog partition, some keys may fail and these transactions will fail and be rollbacked. As a result, the first key on topic A that once consumed will cause the state store push to fail, will block its partition till the broker is up again.

Comment: I would think that the stream consumption would continue but some of the data would not be stored until the responsible broker was back online. That being said, I still have no solid idea. I haven’t found anything in the documentation that states otherwise. The main reason I believe that consumption would continue is because the “replication.factor” setting has a default of 1. It seems like if that setting could totally stop consumption, the default value would be slightly larger, and the documentation would state it.